# Why this code output 3

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

I found this piece of code, originally here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
    int p = 0;
    p = p++ + ++p;
    printf("p=%d\n", p);

}
```

I guessed the output will be 2, but when I compiled the code and I execute it, the output was 3, why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: just to be sure: are you looking for an explanation for the output for this undefined behavior?

Comment: Read the assembly code generated by your compiler.

Comment: Please try searching to see if a question has already been asked (time and time again) before asking it!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Um... what search term would you use? Assume you are a beginner and you know nothing about undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mysticial Good point. I tried just now and it was quite difficult. Still voting to close, but I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart These are one of the few dupe questions that (although annoyingly common), I will not downvote because they're almost impossible to search for. So I just close as dupe and move on.

Answer (score 6):

```
p = p++ + ++p;
```

is undefined behaviour. Read about [Sequence point.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)